# where clause not working in codigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am showing products in a page with a where clause. I am selecting everything from the product table where the category is vegetable, but it's not working. I am new in CodeIgniter. I also checked many questions on the Internet, but nothing is working. If there is anything in this code that is wrong, please tell me.

[image: my table]

**The controller part:**

```
<?php
class products_list extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');     //to load css base url
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model("pagination_model");
        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->library('table');
}


function vegetables(){

    $this ->load->view('includes/header1');

    $config['base_url']='http://localhost/mah/index.php/products_list/vegetables';

    $vegetable="Vegetable";
    $config['total_rows']= $this->db->get_where('product', $vegetable)->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open']='<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close']='</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->pagination_model->
            fetch_product($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view("product_display",    $data);

    $this ->load->view('includes/footer');

}

public function article($id)
{
    $this ->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->model('articles_model', 'product');
    $article = $this->product->find($id);
    $this->load->view('product_details', compact('article'));
}

}
?>
```

**The model part:**

```
<?php
class pagination_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function record_count() {
        $where="category='vegetable'";
        return $this->db->count_all("product");
    }

    public function fetch_product($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

        $query = $this->db->get("product");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller method :**

cutomise your links as per your requirements and  base_url as well

```
   public function vegetables() {
    $data = array('title' => 'Products');
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'products_list/vegetables';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->pagination_model->countRows('products');
    $config['per_page'] = 5;

    $config['attributes'] = array('class' =>'item');

    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="active item">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["products"] = $this->pagination_model->getProducts('',$config["per_page"],$page);
    $data["categoriesData"] = $this->pagination_model->getProducts('vegetable',$config["per_page"],$page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    print_r($data);die;
    //$this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('product_display',$data);
    //$this->load->view('templates/footer');    
}
```

**Your model :**

**getProducts fetch both type of data**

1: if u provide category as first param then it return categories data

2: Otherwise fetch whole table;

```
   public function getProducts($category = NULL, $limit = NULL, $start = NULL)
  {
    $limit = $limit == NULL ? '' : $limit;
    $start = $start == NULL ? '' : $start;
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    if (empty($category)) 
    {
         $query = $this->db->get('products');
    }
    else 
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('products', array('category' => $category));
    }


    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
 // total count method 

 public function countRows($table) {
    if (empty($table)) return false;
     return $this->db->count_all($table);
}
```

**last but not the least :**

add this in controller __contruct() method

```
public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('url','text','html','form'));
    $this->load->library(array('session','form_validation','pagination'));
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('YourModel');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this...

```
$config['total_rows']= $this->db->get_where('product', array('title' => $vegetable))
->num_rows();
```

Comment: I think you need to use the `category` column instead of `title`.